# When I try to print a string from my array it is not working (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, io

### Here is my code:

What I am trying to do is have the user input a bunch of strings and then the user says which string on the list you just wrote that the program will say back to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int amount = 0;
int listnum;
string inpu;


void input(string in){
cout << "Enter a word" << endl;
cin >> in;
}



int main()
{
cout << "How many strings do you want to enter." << endl;
cin >> amount;

string list1[amount];
for(int x = 0; x < amount; x++){
    input(inpu);
    list1[x] = inpu;

    if(x == amount-1){
        cout << "Which word on the list do you want to use?" << endl;
        cin >> listnum;
        cout << list1[listnum] << endl;

    }
}
}
```

I am not sure what is happening so I really would love the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what problem you are having. I see a problem with this though:

```
void input(string in){
    cout << "Enter a word" << endl;
    cin >> in;
}
```

Try passing a *reference* to your variable instead:

```
void input(string &in){
cout << "Enter a word" << endl;
cin >> in;
}
```

Or you can pass a pointer:

```
void input(string *in){
cout << "Enter a word" << endl;
cin >> *in; //Now that this is a pointer, you need to add a * before the variable name when you want to access it.
}
```

If you pass a pointer, make sure you call your function with a pointer though:

`input(&inpu);`

Passing pointers is the only way to do it in C. You will probably never have to use it in C++ unless you are calling a C function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you say in C++ with plain arrays. The C++ solution for that is by using the STL library that gives you the std::vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    int main() {
        vector<string> list1;//This creates a vector 
        string in = "";
        int amount = 0;
        int listnum = 0;


        cout << "How many strings do you want to enter." << endl;
        cin >> amount;

        //This for loop will append the item into the vector list
        //The for loop will control how many item will be appended to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            cout << "Enter a word" << endl;
            cin >> in;
            //The push back function will push the string into the vecot
            list1.push_back(in);
        }

        //This will ask the user for the index position of the word
        cout << "Which index on the list do you want to use?" << endl;
        cin >> listnum;

        //This line of code will output the string that the user wants
        cout << list1[listnum] << endl;


        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The asker is probably using gcc or something, these compilers allow for `string list1[amount]` where `amount` is not a constant.